# Connecting SonarLint into sonaqube server

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have **eclipse NEON.3** with **SonarLint 3.0.0** and while try to connect sonarLint with **SonarQube 6.3.1.21392**.

To connect the SonarQube with sonar lint, we try to install the required softwares by using the link http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/ in eclipse(Help -> Install New Softwares)

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. 
Software being installed: SonarQube Java Configuration Helper 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE) Missing requirement: 
SonarQube Integration for Eclipse JDT 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: SonarQube Java Configuration Helper 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE) To: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt [3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE]
```

Kindly advice us how to fix this issue

Comment: Try to uninstall all components of SonarLint (in Help-> Installation details) and then try to install again.

Comment: @DuarteMeneses the same error occurred again.

Comment: You should install SonarLint from http://eclipse.sonarlint.org/ or from the official marketplace (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace). The latest version is 3.1.0. Also note that with version 3.0.0 (which you had installed) you were already able to connect to a SonarQube server.

Comment: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group is the old SonarQube Eclipse plugin. This is not SonarLint.